# Makefile multiline command does not work in Docker properly

Tags: docker, sed, makefile, subshell

I am trying to compile HTML from Markdown. My `makefile` looks like:

```
MD = pandoc \
    --from markdown --standalone

# ...

$(MD_TARGETS):$(TARGET_DIR)/%.html: $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.md
    mkdir -p $(@D); \
    $(MD) --to html5 $< --output $@; \
    sed -i '' -e '/href="./s/\.md/\.html/g' $@
```

When I run this on local machine everything works.

When I run the same in Docker I get the following error:

```
mkdir -p /project/docs; \
pandoc --from markdown --standalone --to html5 /project/source/changelog.md --output /project/docs/changelog.html; \
sed -i '' -e '/href="./s/\.md/\.html/g' /project/docs/changelog.html
sed: can't read : No such file or directory
makefile:85: recipe for target '/project/docs/changelog.html' failed
make: *** [/project/docs/changelog.html] Error 2
```

Consequent call of `make` gives the same error but with another file:

```
sed: can't read : No such file or directory
makefile:85: recipe for target '/project/docs/todo.html' failed
```

Obviously, make somehow tries `sed` earlier than HTML is done.
But I use multiline syntax `; \` of make so as to avoid using subshell.
I also tried `&& \` but neither of them works. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you have been misled by your "obvious" conclusion *Obviously, make somehow tries sed earlier than HTML is done*  :)  That's not at all what the problem is.  Review your error message more carefully:

```
sed: can't read : No such file or directory
```

Note the `can't read :`; there's supposed to be a filename there.  It should say something like `can't read foobar:`.  So clearly `sed` is trying to read a file with the name of empty string.  Here's the line you're running:

```
sed -i '' -e '/href="./s/\.md/\.html/g' /project/docs/changelog.html
```

The clear culprit here is the empty string argument to `-i`.  The sed man page describes the `-i` option as:

```
   -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

          edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```

Note how (a) the *SUFFIX* is optional, and (b) there's no space between the argument and its option.  In your example you added a space, which causes sed to believe that the *SUFFIX* was not provided and to treat the next argument (`''`) as the filename to be operated on.

I'm not sure why it worked when you ran it from the command line: I have to assume that your command line version didn't include the empty string or else it didn't include a space between the `-i` and the `''`.

Use one of:

```
sed -i'' -e '/href="./s/\.md/\.html/g' $@
```

or

```
sed --in-place= -e '/href="./s/\.md/\.html/g' $@
```

Comment: In mac os there is space between `-i` and argument: `sed [-Ealn] [-e command] [-f command_file] [-i extension] [file ...]`

Comment: Ah.  I don't use MacOS so I wouldn't know.  To run in Docker, though, you need to be looking at the GNU/Linux docs not the MacOS docs, since Docker runs GNU/Linux (even on MacOS... unless you're doing something very _interesting_ :)).